# how to pass a python variable into a bash script?

Tags: bash, python3, environment-variables

Can we pass a python variable into the bash environment, without invoking python environment in bash script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
subprocess.call(['bash','./script.sh',{param1},{param2},{etc}])
```

You accept the variables as `$1`, `$2` etc in "script.sh"